# Is Android java getResource.getIdentfier exist in IOS Swift?

Tags: android, ios, swift, uitextview

My application has so many data. So There are so many textfield. Therefore I want to manage textView in iOS swift in the same way.

```
    area1Layer = new TextView[25];
       for(int k = 0; k < layer1; k++){// 층수 SET
            area1Layer[k] = (TextView)findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("layer"+(k+1),"id","kr.soen.areacard"));
            area1Layer[k].setText(Integer.toString(k + 1) + "0" +ho1);
       }
```

Comment: You can manage using tag.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to identify the respective UITextField/UITextView seperately. This can be done by assigning different tags to the respective textfields/textviews.

```
 let textField1: UITextField = UITextField()
 textField1.tag = 1
 let textField2: UITextField = UITextField()
 textField2.tag = 2
```

and in the UITextFieldDelegate method,

```
 func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField.tag == 1 {
      //Type your code here
    }
    if textField.tag == 2 {
      //Type your code here
    }
 }
```

Also you could assign outlets to each textfield/textview, and use the outlets to check.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
```

and in the UITextFieldDelegate method,

```
 func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == textField1 {
      //Type your code here
    }
    if textField == textField2 {
      //Type your code here
    }
 }
```

The same can be done in the case of UITextView as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to identify each `UITextField` or `UITextView` separately and accordingly manipulate them. You can do it in the following way:

```
let textView1: UITextView = UITextView()
textView1.tag = 1

let textView2: UITextView = UITextView()
textView2.tag = 2

self.view.addSubview(textView1)
self.view.addSubview(textView2)
```

For identifying between different view objects, you can use `.tag` property in `iOS` by setting `.tag` in the above way.

To get different `UITextView` added to the `self.view` as a `subView` in `swift`, you can do the following:

```
if let textViewObject: AnyObject = self.view.viewWithTag(2) {
   // first check is to identify if there is a given view with the tag
   if let textView: UITextView = textViewObject as? UITextView {

   }
}
```

Comment: Change textView1.tag = 2 to textView1.tag = 1

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is iOS uses an number based tag while Android uses a text key. You can accomplish the same thing with both. In iOS store all your labels in a collection and modify per tag. The collection type and syntax specifics for setting the tag depend on the way you wright your views.

Answer (score -1):

After setting the tag via interface builder or `view.tag = myTag;` you can do something like:

```
for (int x=0; x<strings.count; x++){
    UITextView *view = [self.view viewWithTag:x];
    view.text = strings[x];
}
```